# Error on ngrok tunnel connection on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory, pyngrok

I'm following an example tutorial, so I am able to use Flask with Google Colab. When i run the code below, everything works fine, but when i try to visit the page i get a tunnel not found error.

```
!pip install flask 
!pip install flask-ngrok

from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from flask import Flask, render_template 

#Running the flask app 
app = Flask(__name__)
#We need to start ngrok when the app is run 
run_with_ngrok(app)
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello, World!'

app.run()
```

Exact error is:

```
Tunnel 5a0d870b1966.ngrok.io not found
```

In the tutorial that i'm following everything works fine. Any help please?

Comment: this appears to be a common issue faced by many folks, after the recent collab commit. I am also trying to find a solution to this.